# Как переключиться на свое Activity без потери пользовательского ввода?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Я открываю Activity другого приложения, читаю через Accessibility Service данные оттуда и хочу переключиться обратно на свое Activity из сервиса, но посредством Context.startActivity c пустым Intent, Activity теряет пользовательский ввод. При этом, если я вручную открою недавние приложения и переключусь на свое - то ввод не теряется. Как мне добиться такого же поведения программно?

В данный момент самое подходящее, что я нашел - это дважды вызвать `AccessibilityService.performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)`, но это мне не очень подходит.

Я пробовал установить флаг `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`, при этом открывается Activity, на долю секунды мелькает предыдущий ввод, который сразу перерисовывается с пустыми полями.

Comment: Лично мне не очень понятно что вы делаете, но, может быть, вам надо просто не пустой интент запускать, но интенет, в который вы программно положите данные, которые надо передать?

Comment: Да, такой вариант есть, и я к нему прибегну, если не смогу найти решение, но он не очень подходит. Сервис, из которого я возвращаюсь обратно на свое Activity, не должен знать что находится в форме, поэтому неправильно было бы создавать дополнительную зависимость.

Comment: Попробуйте в манифесте у активити прописать launchMode singleInstance

Comment: С этим параметром активити совсем не запускается. Странно то, что если я руками выберу приложение из списка запущенных - то все работает именно так, как я хочу. Хотелось бы сделать ровно то же самое. По идее, флаг FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY должен провоцировать такое поведение, но активити как будто перерисовывается после отображения

Comment: Т.к. мне всё ещё не понятно что именно вы делаете, то буду продолжать гадать. Возможно вам надо просто сохранять состояние в самой актвиити? Т.е. использовать onSaveInstanceState метод, в котором сохранить данные и в onCreate, например, эти данные восстановить? Вы отслеживали какие методы жизненного цикла вызываются у вашей активити в процессе работы программы? Возможно тут будет подсказка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением оказалось использовать флаг Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT